# Etherscan Not Showing Token Holder Data

Tags: solidity

The contract of 0xf263292e14d9D8ECd55B58dAD1F1dF825a874b7c can be found on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/token/0xf263292e14d9D8ECd55B58dAD1F1dF825a874b7c#balances)

But the token holder is not shown, pls see [here](https://etherscan.io/token/tokenholderchart/0xf263292e14d9D8ECd55B58dAD1F1dF825a874b7c)

Can someone help?

Comment: Contact Etherscan support.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Please inform us here if you found what the issue was.